# Google Spreadsheet highlight closest future date

Tags: google-sheets

In a range of dates I need to highlight closest future date.
In practice I have two columns and I want to highlight closest dates in each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming data range is A3:B17 here is custom formatting formula for the range:

```
'Format cell if equals to'

=ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(A$3:A$17>TODAY(),A$3:A$17)))
```